# Why if loop is causing unexpected end of file (code attached) (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, loops, if-statement

This code is causing

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp64\www\pss\wp-content\themes\pss-theme\index.php on line 18

```
<?php 

get_header();

                    if (have_posts()) :
                    $count = 1; 
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 


get_template_part ('content');

get_sidebar(); 

get_footer(); 

?>
```

But if I move if, count and while from index.php,

```
<?php 

get_header();

get_template_part ('content');

get_sidebar(); 

get_footer(); 

?>
```

to the top of the content template part like this:

```
            <?php       if (have_posts()) :
                    $count = 1; 
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="post-content u-cf">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                        <div class="post-thumbnail u-cf">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail')  ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

            <h2 class="post">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p class="post-info">
                                <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                            <?php 
                            $categories = get_the_category(); 
                            $separator = ", ";
                            $output = '';

                            if ($categories) {
                                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                    $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator;
                                }
                                echo trim ($output, $separator);
                            }
                            ?>
                            |
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php the_time('j/m/Y'); ?>
                            </p>


                <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <hr>

                        <?php   if ( 2 === $count ) { ?>
                            <div class="main-content-advert">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem impsum</p>
                            </div>
                        <hr>
                            <?php }
                        $count++; ?>
                        </div>   
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php
                else :
                    echo '<p> No Content found</p>';

                endif; 

?>

    </article>
        </div>
```

The error is not present.

Now, I understand that it has got something to do with the loop or the count?

Comment: you missed `endwhile;` in your code

Comment: I believe it is there - 8th line from bottom, excluding white lines.

Comment: Above the 3rd snippet is your updated code?. if yes your is working fine. what you want to achieve?

Comment: 1st snippet code executed an error. When I moved the code as per 2nd and 3rd snippet - no error occurs. I have not updated anything as of yet. I am guessing that the beginning and end of the loop should be within the same file?

Comment: I am guessing that the beginning and end of the loop should be within the same file? -- yes.

Comment: you can use like this `<?php 

        get_header();

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            get_template_part ('content');

        endwhile; 

        get_sidebar(); 

        get_footer(); 

    ?>`

Comment: I want to exclude the front and back of the loop of the content file and move it to index file, without causing the error when running.

Comment: But then my counter will be gone?

Comment: i think you can declare `counter ` variable as global.

Comment: I can`t. It cocks it up completely. The code only works when the loop is inside the content file. If I exclude it, the loop goes tits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is completely normal, that error its expected because you are missing the end tags of the `if` and the `while`.

You **cant** have those in a different file, `PHP` expects the start and end to be in the same file.

Its not like its going to do the `get_XXXX` functions and create a big file with all those parts and then start with the content of them.

If you want to have the variable `$count` to be in the template part, move the end tags to your index, and have only the content in the content template, that is his purpose ;)

```
<?php
get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
    $count = 1234;
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part('template-parts/post/content');
    endwhile;
else :
    echo '<p> No Content found</p>';

endif;
?>
</article>
</div> 
<?php
get_sidebar();

get_footer();
?>
```

then in `content.php` use `global` to get the variable that is not in scope:

```
<?php
global $count;
var_dump($count);//THIS WILL SHOW THE NUMBER 1234
?>

<div class="post-content u-cf">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
    <div class="post-thumbnail u-cf">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail') ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

    <h2 class="post">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="post-info">
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <?php
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $separator = ", ";
        $output = '';

        if ($categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator;
        }
        echo trim ($output, $separator);
        }
        ?>
        |
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php the_time('j/m/Y'); ?>
    </p>


    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <hr>

<?php if ( 2 === $count ) { ?>
    <div class="main-content-advert">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem impsum</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
<?php }
$count++;
?>
</div>
```

you can find more info here [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: thank you.Is there a way to exclude everything after the while and before the end tag to a different file without breaking the if count function?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example using your code. i used `1234` as the number so you can see its the same value being accessed.